# Google Chrome is slow to localhost

Tags: google-chrome, performance, localhost

For some reason Google Chrome is slow when I'm working against localhost. I had the same problem in Firefox 3.5 but I changed some IPv6 setting in `about:config` which fixed the issue. I think the same problem occurs in Google Chrome, but I can't find out how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just an idea : do you have a line that looks like this :

```
::1 localhost
```

in your hosts (it should be somewhere like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, if I remember correctly) file ?

If yes, comment that line by adding a `#` at the beginning.

This way, the only line that's about localhost should be

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

which is IPv4.

It might help, if your problem is really caused by IPv6.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Was just a wild guess, but nice to seen it worked ! (might be useful one day on another, actually ! )

Comment: @blahblah - You should mark Pascal's answer as "accepted". @Pascal - thanks so much for this fix, this was really slowing me down as I was testing sites locally in Chrome.

Comment: http://crazyviraj.blogspot.com/2009/09/fix-for-slow-firefoxchrome-connects-to.html

Comment: This makes a huge difference.  Both lines were commented out for me in Windows 7, so I uncommented the IPv4 line and everything works great now.

Comment: I've been using this fix up until Chrome 8, but now that Chrome 9 has been released, it seems to be slow again. Has anyone found a fix for the current version?

Comment: @Pascal: Thank you so much. This issue as been annoying me forever.

Comment: Can someone explain why does this work?

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Win7 x64). As soon as wi-fi is on, accessing localhost is slow, when I disable wi-fi then it's fast. Tested in IE, FF and Chrome. NB I do not use any web filtering.

Comment: After trying loads of different things, @RustyX gave me the best answer. If I turn off the Wi-Fi and just use the ethernet connection, it works sooo fast. Thanks dude.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting cookies and site data of localhost from chrome settings worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).