# Why is Chrome much slower at loading local files than online webpages?

Tags: google-chrome, ssd, performance, speed

Chrome is very slow to load some HTML pages/websites stored locally on my SSD.

For example, if I [download the NumPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/) and try to load the pages while disconnected from the Internet, it takes many seconds or longer (with a "Resolving host" messages on the bottom of the browser). The page eventually loads with no errors, but the latency is consistent. It loads *much slower* than if I had accessed the website on the Internet.

However, if I do the same with the [downloaded Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/download.html) while offline, it loads instantly with no errors. It loads *faster* than if I had accessed the website on the Internet.

What causes this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: See if this helps : https://superuser.com/questions/43823/google-chrome-is-slow-to-localhost

Comment: Looks like I need admin privileges to do that. Is there another way?

Comment: Windows or Linux? And why no admin permissions?

Comment: Both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @harrymc I was able to get an admin to do that, but it did not solve this issue.